# Pointer to vector of objects C++, how to access objects?

Tags: c++, pointers, vector

So I have a pointer to a vector filled with objects. What would the syntax be to access the objects within the element?

Vector:

`std::vector<Fork> fork_;`

Pointer:

`std::vector<Fork> * fork_;`

`fork_ = &new_fork_;`

Answer (score 0):

You access vectors like an array, using `vector_name[index_no]`, or, ---you can use `vector_name.at(index)` to also obtain the object at a certain index.

Comment: Can you link documentation for `std::vector::at` taking an iterator?

Comment: @Tas Ah, you're right, there is no function overload for doing such!

Answer (score 0):

There are actually several ways, standard element access includes:

1. [`operator[]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator_at)
2. [`at`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/at)
3. [`front`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/front)
4. [`back`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/back)
5. [`data`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/data)

You can also use iterators which are required for standard algorithms, which are the C++ standard for working with containers. You can get the integrators a number of ways as well:

1. [`cbegin`/`begin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/begin)
2. [`cend`/`end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end)
3. [`rcbegin`/`rbegin`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rbegin)
4. [`rcend`/`rend`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/rend)

Any of the above can be accessed with the pointer operator, for example:

```
fork_->at(0);
```

And lastly C++11 provides a for each version of the `for`-loop:

```
for(auto& i : *fork_) cout << i;
```